# From constant object reference to pointer

Tags: c++

In my C++ program I've a base class B and some derived classes D1, D2, etc..
Then I've a function taking as parameter the derived class D1, passed by const reference to improve performance, instead of passing it by copy:

```
void appendDerived(const D1& derived)
{
   listOfDerived.append(D1);
}
```

*listOfDerived* is a list of derived classed, so *append* method is the following:

```
void append(Base* base)
{
    if (!base) return;
    m_myList.append(base->clone()); //clone function is defined for each derived and does: return new D1(*this);
}
```

Because of appendDerived takes as argument a const reference, the compiler gives an error in append method, because there's no matching function for *append*.
Solutions I've found are the following:

1. Change the appendDerived function to:

   ```
   void appendDerived(D1 derived)
   {
      listOfDerived.append(&derived);
   }
   ```

   so passing the argument by value, but with a performance penalty.
2. Change the appendDerived function to:

   ```
   void appendDerived(D1* derived)
   {
      listOfDerived.append(derived);
   }
   ```

   so passing the argument by pointer, meaning I've to change all the function calls to *appendDerived* in the whole code, with some drawbacks I don't want to list here...
3. Create an intermediate variable before the append:

   ```
   void appendDerived(const D1& derived)
   {
      D1 derived_temp = derived;
      listOfDerived.append(&derived_temp);
   }
   ```

   But seems a too dirty solution...

Do you have any better idea?

Comment: Does `append` need to modify the passed in object (that is, could it take a `Base const*` instead)? Does `append` rely on the fact that the appointed object is kept alive after it has finished executing?

Comment: @ComicSansMS: I've edited the code above coding the *append* implementation. So answering to your question, *append* does not modify the passed object.

Comment: Change your `append` function to take a **const** Base pointer/reference. Change your `clone` function to be `const` if it isn't so already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. is broken because you are passing the address of a local variable.
2. seems OK, but you change the function to take a pointer rather than a reference. This has effect on the caller side.
3. is broken in the same way 1. is.

So, you may use solution 2, but you can also pass a non-const reference:

```
void appendDerived(D1& derived)
{
   listOfDerived.append(&D1);
}
```

A few things to think about:

- `append()` takes a pointer. Does it make sense for `appendDerived()` to take a reference?
- Which one of `append` or `appendDerived` need the parameter to be pointer/reference to `const`? It could be that you need `const` in both places, rather than non-const as suggested above. In other words, change `append` to

.

```
void append(const Base* base)
{
    if (!base) return;
    m_myList.append(base->clone()); //clone needs to be const, as it should be.
}
```

This needs `clone()` to be `const`:

```
virtual Base* clone() const;
                      ^^^^^
```

Comment: So the issue was related to my const! I originally put const because there was no need to change the passed object since I need simply to append it.

Comment: I thought (forgive me, I'm a C++ newby.. :-) ) that the use of const was to forbid the change of the value of the passed argument. But I see that forbid the address reading of the variable address too, using the &.

Comment: @user3253359 You are passing a reference to const, meaning you cannot modify the object it refers to. You cannot bind that to a non-const pointer, because that would allow you to modify the same object via the pointer. OTOH you could bind it to `const` pointer.

Comment: Just to better understand the picture, I've edited the code above coding the implementation of the *append* method. Since it's made like this, are your points 1 and 3 about brokage still true?

Comment: So at the end what is better in your opinion? Remove the const from the argument passing or putting it in the *append* function like this: Base const* ?

Comment: @user3253359 Yes, points 1. and 3. are still true. Also, see n.m's comment to your post. I think it is better to have `const` in both places.

Comment: Monkeys on my brain needs time to elaborate what you told me today about pointers/constants/references, etc... coming from Java, C++ is driving me crazy! :-)

Comment: Based on your editing, can I add const pointers to a non-const pointer list (m_myList)? Or should I've to change the list type too?

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure the list you're making is supposed to be constant or not?
If you have a nonconstant list then it's illegal to try to use a const reference to append to it because you'd be breaking the const.
You need to take only a reference and a const reference.

Comment: No, the list is not made of const object pointers, but simply of object pointers.

Comment: In this case it's illegal to add a const reference to your list. You need to remove the const to make it work (as the other answer said). You could change the other function and make it accept a const ref as well but you wouldn't be able to add it to the list in the end if the list itself doesn't contain const elements.

Comment: @user3253359 It is actually OK, because you are not adding a `const` pointer to the list, you are adding the result of a call to `clone()`, which should be a non-const pointer.

Comment: @juanchopanza Sorry I'me confused: you're saying here that 'clone()' should be a non-const pointer, but in your editing it's declared const

Comment: it only means that clone() doesn't change base because if it changed base then you couldn't use it with a const reference. Since you're making a copy you're not changing base so you should declare it as const.